# how to retrieve the data from sharepoint2010 different lists to in grid view

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I need to add the some columns information from the two different list to gridview please how to write the code get the result

Comment: Please read the page [ask] and give more information: are the list in the same web, same site collection ? What kind of gridview do you want to populate ? ASP.Net ? SPGridView ? Desktop app framework GridView ? Are the list bound with the same content types ? Which version of SP ?

Comment: also, I think it belongs to [sharepoint.se]

Answer (score 0):

Here' some examples

http://snahta.blogspot.com/2008/09/using-spgridview-in-custom-code.html

http://snahta.blogspot.com/2009/04/reading-list-items-in-datatable.html

Answer (score 0):

MSDN is also offering a free visual howto on that topic.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb466219(v=office.12).aspx

It's easy. Just put the Grid on your page and bind it to your data.